# How github manages to reflect a user details everywhere when a user updates his/her profile

Tags: github, redux, frontend

Suppose a user updates his/her profile details in GitHub then after sometime those details will reflect everywhere in the website.

How GitHub managed to perform this usecase?

Comment: I'd assume updating your profile, it updates a database, and when github queries the database, it will have the updated profile

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
Then does GitHub makes a server call whenever the user appears on the web page?
@RuiqiLi

Comment: There may be caching involved, so that's why it may take a while for the update to appear